# Django full text search: TrigramDistance not working

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search

I am using Django 2.0 and postgresql 9.6.

I have installed pg_trgm extension in the postgresql

I am trying to understand how triagram works: I am trying the following. I want words nearer to "sridam" to be matched using triagram

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import TrigramDistance
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery, SearchRank, SearchVector
vector = SearchVector('title',config='english_unaccent', weight='A') + SearchVector('description',config='english_unaccent', weight='B')
query = SearchQuery('sridam',config='english_unaccent')
Article.objects.annotate(distance=TrigramDistance(vector, query)).filter(distance__lte=0.7).order_by('distance')


ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: tsvector <-> tsquery
LINE 1: ...SCE("articles_article"."description", '')), 'B')) <-> plaint...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't calculate the Trigram distance between a `SearchVector` and a `SearchQuery` because *"A trigram is a group of three consecutive characters."*.

As specified in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#trigramdistance) `TrigramDistance` *"accepts a field name or expression, and a string or expression. Returns the Trigram distance between the two arguments."*.

Comment: Will trigrams be faster like SearchVector w.r.t performance. Also we can add SearchVectorField to our model and populate with triggers. Is that possible with trigrams

Answer (score 0):

Before using postgres extensions you have to apply extension migrations to your model.

### SOLUTION 1

Make empty migration file:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations --empty yourapp
```

then go to the new migration file and add following

```
from django.db import migrations
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import TrigramExtension

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    operations = [
        TrigramExtension()
    ]
```

Finally run `python3 manage.py migrate` to apply migrations to your database and you are ready to use the extension.

### SOLUTION 2

You can go to `psql` console and apply migrations directly:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```